# Protein about to expire

Tags: protein-shakes

I have whey protein which is almost expired but some still left. Is that bad idea to consume anymore?

> *English is not my first language, please edit for clarity, then remove this comment!*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about food safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK to use it, it's not expired YET right? :D

There are even places that sell almost expired protein
http://www.bestpricenutrition.com/clearance.html

so you should be fine!

Answer (score -2):

Is it a 'Expiration Date' or a "Best Consumed By" or a "Sell by" date? If it is past it's expiration date I would try to consume it quickly, but it should be generally safe to use for a month or so.